# Jar dependency - Application server classpath vs adding it to the application war itself

Tags: java, jar, classpath, war, weblogic-10.x

We have an installation of Weblogic 10.3.6. 
An application running on it needs the following jar

```
com.oracle.ws.http_client_1.3.0.0.jar
```

The above jar is located in the server bundle Oracle\Middleware\modules\com.oracle.ws.http_client_1.3.0.0.jar

What's the right approach?
Should this jar (appears to be a system library written by Oracle, not found on mvnrepository site) be added to the server classpath or should I add it to the application archive (war)?? Thanks.

Update: Also the above jar comes bundled with Weblogic (not added to classpath by default though) and is not found in maven public repo. So, this is not meant to be added to the application directly?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

1. If the jar is part of the application server environment/build I would not add it to the war/ear file. It should be availble through out all the env DIT/UAT/PROD (envs need to be consistent with prod). Also when the app serever fixes are applied or server is upgaded we will be using the lastest jar.
2. In other cases(external) it would be best to package it in war in order to avoid issues while migrating from env to env.

Answer (score 9):

Best place to place JAR files and other dependencies is to pack it
within the WAR rather than keeping into `system` `classpath`. By doing this
you have following advantages.

1. WAR file is self-sustainable and robust without any dependency on
   it's `container`.
2. Same WAR file, without any packaging change can be
   deployed to DEV, IT, QA, Demo, Test, Production, blah, blah or any environment
   present.
3. No issues between `system` & `webapp` `classloaders`.

There may be debates as by packing everything in the WAR file may end
up increasing the WAR file **size** significantly. But it is really
frustrating when there is a *funny* production error out of no where in
middle of night just because you *missed* to **update** `http_client_1.3.0.0.jar` to
`http_client_1.4.x.y.jar` and *others plainly state that exact same WAR file
was working perfectly in testing environment.*

From my experience, I believe **consistency** of a WAR file is an important aspect. And, hence, suggest you to pack every required JAR file into the WAR, until and unless the JAR is provided implicitly by the container.

- Disk space cost per GB = $1
- Effort to resolve inconsistency issue = $50
- Giving up midnight sleep to resolve a crazy issue = **priceless**

:)

Comment: The jar in question is only bundled with Weblogic Server and is not available in any of the public repositories (mvn repo, apache repo) etc. So com.oracle.ws.http_client_1.3.0.0.jar is not meant to be bundled as a part of the WAR file? That's my original issue in the question

Comment: Since theere are multiple JARs for HttpClient present for the classloader to load, I'm suggesting to pack it inside the WAR. And that's completely fine.

Comment: "increasing the WAR file size significantly" in these days of *enormous* disk drives, the size of a WAR is rarely an issue.

Answer (score 3):

It depends. When you are inserting dependency inside the classpath it's loaded by default classloader - then e.g. all enums and singletons are initialized by this default classloader. Depending on server's configuration all applications would share those instances or they might get their own independently instantiated.

Additionally when you add dependency to the class path it becomes available to all applications on server, whether they need it or not.

If you got only one application, it wouldn't make a difference. If there is more, it would be safer to add JAR to the application unless you explicitly want to make this library (and this particular version) globally available on server for all deployed WARs to use.

EDIT:

Apparently you can be sure that each application would have its own instances of enums and singletons  as described [here](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E19501-01/819-3659/beadf/index.html). So your only issue in classpath approach would be if different applications would require different versions of the same library.

Comment: I do agree that "it depends" but in this instance, the jar is developed by Oracle and is bundled with the EE server. So it's not meant to be added to the WAR file?

Comment: If it's bundled with EE server it should be available to all applications on that server out of the box and so you shouldn't add it to WAR. There shouldn't be any need to adding it manually to classpath as well. If you want to deploy to some other server which may not have it, simply make 2 versions of a WAR and deploy the one suitable for the server.